# How to unlink file from children dir of parent dir? PHP

Tags: php

I want to unlink an image file from children dir of a parent dir.
I developing this project in a director folder under my website (mysite/project) but when i complete the project i will move to another hosting package.
Whic code i need use for stable running in all directories?

I get this error:

> Warning: unlink(../../images/urunler/deneme-urun.jpg): No such file or directory in /home/admin/public_html/eticaret/admin/includes/updateproduct.php on line 120

My folder structure:

[click here to see my folder structure](http://prntscr.com/oha0rt)

```
$delete = unlink("../../images/products/".$img);
```

Comment: What path did you use to link it?

Comment: i used stackoverflow editor first time but imgur url doesn't working. I used lightshot (printscreen software) on my pc.

Comment: It looks like you haven't copied the whole warning. Can you complete it?

Comment: I added the entire error.

Comment: The script with the warning is 3 subdirectories removed from the `public_html` and you think it is 2 removed. Try: `unlink("../../../images/products/".$img);`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I tried but i get same error: Warning: unlink(../../../images/urunler/deneme-urun.jpg): No such file or directory in /home/admin/public_html/eticaret/admin/includes/updateproduct.php on line 120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before running `unlink()` command you can check the existence of the file to get rid of such error

```
$path = "../../images/products/".$img;
if (file_exists(path)) {   
    unlink($path)                        
}
```

Better is using the full directory path (absolute path). An example, let your project structure is
[image]

and your unlinking code is in `script.php`, then your can get full absolute path the following way

```
$path = __DIR__ . "/../../images/products/{$img}";
if (file_exists(path)) {   
    unlink($path)                        
}
```

Comment: I tried if (!file_exists) but dosn't work. I get same error: Warning: unlink(../../images/urunler/deneme-urun.jpg): No such file or directory in /home/admin/public_html/eticaret/admin/includes/updateproduct.php on line 122

Comment: Updated the answer. use `file_exists(path)` and use absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

1. as the script is run from "*public_html/eticaret/admin/includes/*" you need to .. traverse back 3 directories to get to *public_html* which is a common ancestor folder for both image and script
2. according to your directory image your images are in *public_html/myproject/images/products/* and according to error detailed in your comment you are trying to delete from *images/urunler/* I assume *urunler* is the actual project name.

if the folder containg your images is urunler try `$delete = unlink("../../../images/urunler/".$img);`
if the container folder is products try `$delete = unlink("../../../images/products/".$img);`

if that fails try using an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers.
I have a fault on this topic.
Image name is xxx.jpg in my database but xxx.jpeg in the folder.
but there is an interesting situation: if you have an image as .jpeg format, you can open on browser as .jpg format.
I've tried a lot of methods to solve the above error, but I've found that.
I using chrome browser now.

So i solved my problem yet :)